# php to asp.net: howto display sql results in a view

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Firstly, im a PHP developer trying to get my head around asp.net.

so i have created a basic MVC project.

I have a query without the fields known (ie. select * from products) how do I:

1. execute in Controller - my attempt:

   ```
   public ActionResult getProducts() 
   {

       using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ToString()))
       {
           string sql = "select * from products";

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
           cn.Open();
           SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);              
       }

       return View();  
   }
   ```
2. how do i pass the results to a View and then loop through them like:

   ```
   foreach ($data as $key => $val) 
   {
       echo $key.' = '.$val.'<br>';
   }
   ```

please help as this is SOOOOO simple in PHP but seems to be very confusing in asp.net.

ps. sorry for the formatting.

cheers,
trav.

Comment: You should think about learning Entity Framework. It is definitely more preffered data access method.

Comment: And you should definitely go through some MVC tutorials, because this question is not only about iterating through result, but also setting view model, passing, using it in view. A lot to learn.

Comment: Everything is always SOOOOOOO simple in the language you know.

Comment: @jfar: When I moved from ASP.NET MVC to PHP MVC, it became really simple:) There is much more philosophy in ASP.NET.

Comment: thanks guys, i understand the MVC concept, im trying to convert a very custom php app to asp.net.  running custom sql and looping over the results is a big part of the app.  can someone point me in the right direction please.  simply, i have a sql query and i want the output results without all the bells and whistles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need a model class:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And in your controller:

```
public ActionResult getProducts() 
    {

                    var products = new List<Product>();

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ToString()))
        {
            string sql = "select * from products";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection); 

                            //read the results
                            while(rdr.Read() )
                            {
                                //map or hydrate a new product
                                var p = new Product();
                                p.Name = rdr["Name"];
                                p.Id = Int.Parse(rdr["Id"]);
                                p.Price = Int.Parse(rdr["Price"]);

                                //add new product to list we created earlier
                                products.Add( p );
                            }            
        }

        return View(products);  
    }
```

And in the View:

```
     //make sure the page inherits from ViewPage<List<Product>>       

     <% foreach( var product in Model ) { %>
          <%= product.Name %>
     <% } %>
```

One caveat.  Your doing things "the hard way" here by not using an ORM like Entity Framework or Nhibernate and not following best practices by not using a View Model.  Thats fine for just learning of course, just something to be aware of. ;)

Comment: thanks jfar.  How would you adapt this if the sql columns where unknown?  think of a user that is writing their own sql query on the fly.  I don't want to write the model structure explicitly, i want to dynamically build the output based on the users input query.

Comment: @user517169 - I wouldn't.  Your in the statically typed and compiled world now.  Dynamic properties is just not something you do.  You could use a dictionary or something but you'd be way off in left field.